# Programming a Location Grid Map in C#

Tags: c#, grid, location

I would like to know if there are any inbuilt controls in C# with which I can program location grid maps on a X/Y Plane.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is the grid view. You could arrange the columns and rows into a regular grid.

Besides that, .Net makes it very easy to place controls dynamically into containers. You could also do manual drawing which is very straightforward.

Here is an [example of grid painting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/645747c0-7445-4683-9c3a-632eed0322f2/).

And here's an [example of dynamically adding controls to a form](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815780).